# Solving the limit of a recursive sequence

Tags: limits, polynomials

[image]

Here, I'd have to find the limit of the recursive sequence at first. If I assume that the limit *does exist* and assume it to be $L$, then I'd get -
$$
\lim_{n \to+\infty} \frac{t_n}{t_{n-1}}=1 + \lim_{n \to+\infty} \frac{t_{n-2}}{t_{n-1}} + \lim_{n \to+\infty} \frac{t_{n-3}}{t_{n-2}}\times (\frac{t_{n-2}}{t_{n-1}})
$$

So, I'd get $L$ = $1$ + $1/L$ + $1/L^2$. But on solving, I don't get any satisfactory answer, and none of the options match. Can someone tell me where am I possibly going wrong, and how should I manage from there?(Please don't use advanced calculus as I'm just a beginner!)

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused, I'm awful at Latex! But now that's edited, can you please try it out at your end?

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to go through the tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These looks to be the Tribonacci numbers with $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_3=2$.

If you need to solve for $L$ the equation
$$L=1+\frac 1 L+\frac 1 {L^2}$$ it is a cubic equation. Since there is only one real root, use the hyperbolic method (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root)). It should give
$$L=\frac 13 \left(1+4 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{19}{8}\right)\right) \right)\sim 1.83929$$

If you do not know the hyperbolic functions, use Cardano metfod to get
$$L=\frac{1}{3} \left(1+\sqrt[3]{19-3 \sqrt{33}}+\sqrt[3]{19+3 \sqrt{33}}\right)$$

Comment: I'm feeling really ashamed to say that I really know nothing about hyperbolic functions! But I did plot it on desmos and I got the same answer, but how should I proceed from here, as this answer is a root of f(x)=0 and it's such a nasty value!

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi Claude, nice computation, but unfortunately this does not answer the question at all :-( In fact the answer (D) is immediate from the fact that the characteristic polynomial is cubic. @AbhinavTahlani: read the question !

Answer (score 2):

The solution of the recurrence will be of the form

$$t_n=c_0r_0^n+c_1r_1^n+c_2r_2^n$$

and

$$x_0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{t_n}{t_{n-1}}=r_k$$ where $r_k$ is one of the roots of the characteristic polynomial. This polynomial is

$$r^3-r^2-r-1,$$ which fulfills the normalization condition.

As this polynomial has an odd degree, it has no minimum, hence (D). (There is indeed a local minimum $f(1)=-2$ but it does not "count".)